# How to plot 2 trendlines on a single scatterplot? (python)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, trendline

I want to plot **2 trendlines** for **one** scatterplot using Matplotlib in Python but I don't know how. The graph should be similar to this [***target plot***](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/core/lw/2.0/html/tileshop_pmc/tileshop_pmc_inline.html?title=Click%20on%20image%20to%20zoom&p=PMC3&id=3438148_MJMS-11-1-024-g2.jpg) (from [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3438148/), fig.2).

I managed to plot 1 trendline on a scatterplot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDoGa.png) but can't figure out how to plot another trend.

Underneath is what I tried until now:

This proved ok for other parameters that I plotted, but not for this case, which led me to the conclusion that it's not too correct.

```
X = vO2.reshape(-1, 1)
Y = ve.reshape(-1, 1)
linear_regressor = LinearRegression()
linear_regressor.fit(X, Y)
y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(X)
x_pred = linear_regressor.predict(Y)

plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.plot(X, y_pred, '-*',label="O2")
plt.plot(x_pred, Y, '-*',label="vent")
plt.xlabel("VO2 (L/min)")
plt.ylabel("VE (L/min)")
plt.show()
```

and also

```
z1 = np.polyfit(vO2, ve, 1)
p1 = np.poly1d(z1)

z2 = np.polyfit(ve, vO2, 1)
p2 = np.poly1d(z2)

plt.scatter(vO2, ref_vent, label='original')
plt.plot(vO2, p1(vO2), label='trendline')
plt.plot(ve, p2(ve), label='trendline')
plt.show()
```

which also didn't look similar to the target plot.

I don't know how to continue. Thanks in advance!

example dataset:
vo2 = [1.673925  1.9015125 1.981775  2.112875  2.1112625 2.086375  2.13475
2.1777    2.176975  2.1857125 2.258925  2.2718375 2.3381    2.3330875
2.353725  2.4879625 2.448275  2.4829875 2.5084375 2.511275  2.5511
2.5678375 2.5844625 2.6101875 2.6457375 2.6602125 2.6939875 2.7210625
2.720475  2.767025  2.751375  2.7771875 2.776025  2.7319875 2.564
2.3977625 2.4459125 2.42965   2.401275  2.387175  2.3544375]

ve = [ 3.93125     7.1975      9.04375    14.06125    14.11875    13.24375
14.6625     15.3625     15.2        15.035      17.7625     17.955
19.2675     19.875      21.1575     22.9825     23.75625    23.30875
25.9925     25.6775     27.33875    27.7775     27.9625     29.35
31.86125    32.2425     33.7575     34.69125    36.20125    38.6325
39.4425     42.085      45.17       47.18       42.295      37.5125
38.84375    37.4775     34.20375    33.18       32.67708333]

Comment: This reminds me of a titration curve. You can find the turning point by 2nd derivative. Read this article: https://newbedev.com/how-to-apply-piecewise-linear-fit-in-python

Comment: Can you provide example data?

Comment: I edited the post with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you need to find the point, where slope of line changes. I tried 2nd derivative, but it was noisy and I coulnd't find the right spot.

Another way is to try all possible points, calculate left and right regression lines and find pair with best fit (r2 coeff). Give this code a try. It is not complete. I do not know, how to force regression lines to go through point in the middle. And it might be better to work with interpolated data, if there are not enough datapoints.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score


vo2 = [1.673925,1.9015125,1.981775,2.112875,2.1112625,2.086375,2.13475,2.1777,2.176975,2.1857125,2.258925,2.2718375,2.3381,2.3330875,2.353725,2.4879625,2.448275,2.4829875,2.5084375,2.511275,2.5511,2.5678375,2.5844625,2.6101875,2.6457375,2.6602125,2.6939875,2.7210625,2.720475,2.767025,2.751375,2.7771875,2.776025,2.7319875,2.564,2.3977625,2.4459125,2.42965,2.401275,2.387175,2.3544375]

ve = [ 3.93125,7.1975,9.04375,14.06125,14.11875,13.24375,14.6625,15.3625,15.2,15.035,17.7625,17.955,19.2675,19.875,21.1575,22.9825,23.75625,23.30875,25.9925,25.6775,27.33875,27.7775,27.9625,29.35,31.86125,32.2425,33.7575,34.69125,36.20125,38.6325,39.4425,42.085,45.17,47.18,42.295,37.5125,38.84375,37.4775,34.20375,33.18,32.67708333]

x = np.array(vo2)
y = np.array(ve)

sort_idx = x.argsort()
x = x[sort_idx]
y = y[sort_idx]

assert len(x) == len(y)

def fit(x,y):
    p = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    f = np.poly1d(p)
    r2 = r2_score(y, f(x))
    return p, f, r2

skip = 5  # minimal length of split data
r2 = [0] * len(x)  
funcs = {}

for i in range(len(x)):
    if i < skip or i > len(x) - skip:
        continue

    _, f_left, r2_left = fit(x[:i], y[:i])
    _, f_right, r2_right = fit(x[i:], y[i:])

    r2[i] = r2_left * r2_right
    funcs[i] = (f_left, f_right)
    
split_ix = np.argmax(r2)  # index of split
f_left,f_right = funcs[split_ix]   
  
print(f"split point index: {split_ix}, x: {x[split_ix]}, y: {y[split_ix]}")  
  
    
xd = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100)
plt.plot(x, y, "o")
plt.plot(xd, f_left(xd))
plt.plot(xd, f_right(xd))
plt.plot(x[split_ix], y[split_ix], "x")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks better than what I've done :) I have some questions though. why did you cut the data for x and y with [:-5] at the beginning?  Also, the code divides the scatter plot in 2 areas, defined by 2 linear regression lines with the best fit. I was wondering what change would I have to do if I want to obtain 3 areas and plot 3 regression lines. Would it be ok to identify the first 2 areas like this and the third by applying the same algorithm on the remaining data to the right?

Comment: You need some minimal length of data to do the regression, I have chosen 5 points, change it if it makes sense. Three lines could be found, if you used too loops and tried all possible pairs of split points. Get triplets of r2 coefficients, multiply them and find maximum (best fit).

Comment: I have made a mistake and sorted your data in a way, that removed some outliers. I edited the script, now it should be ok, but the fit is much worse. It may not be possible to find reasonable fit with this data.